# What does bluetoothAdapter.getAddress() return when bluetooth is off?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, android-wifi, android-wireless

Probably the question seems weird , but actually is not quite :)

I build an application that will run on different android tablets.

I had also a small problem about finding and unique identifier for each tablet but i chose to find the wifi and bluetooth MAC addresses.

I read  the android documentation and i couldn't found an answer for my question. It is really strange because on the device I work on the bluetoothAdapter.getAddress() returns the actual bluetooth MAC address even if the bluetooth service is turned off, and I don't know why, but this is not the problem. I assume that not all the android tablets are  as special as mine and not all of them will return the bluetooth MAC address if the service is off. But what actually bluetoothAdapter.getAddress() will return normally ? Does it return NULL when the service is off?

If you want to ask why not simply turn on the service and then find the MAC address I will tell you that it is a matter of sense: The app purpose doesn't have anything to do with bluetooth communication between devices and stuff like that, so it's unusual, from the users side, when he opens the app, to see that the tablet requires bluetooth service even if the app is for measuring distances.

I am grateful to those who will answer my question or give a hint! And maybe a solution: how to turn on the bluetooth service without the user to know that. Thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

use this code to enable Bluetooth service

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, RESULT_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old but pretty useful post about unique identification of installations.. Find it [**here**](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

Additional comment: in my opinion it is really bad to add bluetooth permissions to your app manifest when app actually doesn't need BT.. Personally I would wonder WHY and probably I would avoid such an app.. Even worse, I would be pretty annoyed if app turn BT without my permissions using some woobly-jubly workarounds.. Respect your users if u want successful app

Cheers